# What does the [] inside this.state mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does that mean by setting the value of task_one to []?

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            task_one: [],
            task: ""
        }
        this.setTask = this.setTask.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: Assigning empty array

Comment: it is an  empty array  and here is initial value for task_one